# In-App Database in Swift 3

Tags: swift, database, xcode, swift3

I want to create an App with a built-in database to provide a big amount of data in the App. I don't want to access an online database.
I want to edit the database just in Swift if possible and provide updates via App Store Update.
I don't really need functions to add or delete data within the application.

I'm pretty new to iOS development so please don't blame me if it is a stupid question and the solution is very simple.

I searched the web a lot but didn't really find a matching solution.
Most tutorials I found are for older Swift versions and not compatible with Swift 3 and Xcode 8.

What is the best way to do so? Like SQLite or Realm?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Realm is simple and easy to use with a great editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly objective question as different people will have their own opinions on database solutions. I am going to give you the *facts*, it is up to you to make your decision based on that.

Apple provides the CoreData framework built in which is their solution to persisting data. It is written on top of SQLite and exposes a number of methods/classes for your data objects. The syntax can be quite horrible and long winded at times and most developers prefer 3rd party ORMs for this reason.

One such third party ORM is Realm, as you mentioned. I am yet to use it myself but it claims to address the issues with CoreData.

A 3rd party ORM I have used and am experienced in is called SharkORM. It is also written on top of SQLite and has a much friendlier syntax and it is much easier to use with no experience.

It can be downloaded from http://www.sharkorm.com/ and the documentation can be found there also.

Like I said at the beginning this is not my opinion as I havent really considered alternatives, its just fact.